# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstname')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to react and node (express)
I'm trying to get some date from a database ('firstName' and 'lastName'),concatenate and display them in a select tag.

There is what I do:

The request I sent to the database in my node file:

```js
app.get("/employeesName", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT firstname , lastname FROM employees", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

The get request in react:

```js
const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const  getEmployeesNames = () => {
      Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/employeesName").then((response) => {
        setEmployeeList(response.data);
      });
      }; 
          getEmployeesNames();

  },[])
```

I tried something like that to diplsay my data in the select tag:

```html
 <select>
        <option value="">{employeeList[0].firstname+" "+employeeList[0].lastname}</option>
        <option value="">{employeeList[1].firstname+" "+employeeList[1].lastname}</option>         
 </select>
```

When I do that in vs code It works,but just when I refresh my page In the browser I get that error (Cannot read properties of undefined),I think that employeeList is empty on first render. Which Is reasonable as my initial state is an empty array (useState([]);),I tried to initialize
my useState with something like that `useState([{firstname: 'test', lastname: 'test2'}]);` but still get the error

What should be done to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useState([{firstname: 'test', lastname: 'test2'}])
```

This array has one element so `employeeList[1]` will be falsy

---

You can just conditionally render the select:

```
{
    employeeList.length > 0 && (
        <select>
            {
                employeeList.map((emp, index) => <option key={index} value={index}>{emp.firstname + " " + emp.lastname}</option>)
            }
        </select>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the middleware.

```
npm i body-parser
```

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }));
```

I hope you will find it usefull.

Comment: Hi, the question has already an accepted answer, and your content is very different. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your state is,

```js
const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([]);
```

You should use `map` for rendering options. Here is an example.

```
<select>
  {
    employeeList.length > 0 &&                
    employeeList.map((emp, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={index}>{emp?.firstname + " " + emp?.lastname)}</option>
    )
  }
</select>
```

You should also use `?` like `emp?.firstname` on objects. This prevents errors if the `firstname` property does not exist on an `emp` object.